# With N thread only last thread record is passed to next thread group.

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, correlation

In the below test plan Finance applied or document submitted against the last created transaction only. How can I submit document or apply for finance for each transaction.

**User Defined Variables**

- userName
- password
- transactionNumberInUDV

**HTTP Header Manager** 
    content-type

**HTTP Request Defaults**
    default settings

**Setup Thread Group** for token generation.

- JSR223 PreProcessor: to check token exists for the respective user and valid. If Valid then stop the current thread.
- HTTP Request
- JSON Extractor : to extract the date from response
- JSR223 PostProcessor : extracted data saved into csv file.

**Create Treansaction Thread Group**

- HTTP Header Manager: Authorization
- HTTP Request
- JSON Extractor : extract the Transaction Number from response
- JSR223 PostProcessor : `${__setProperty(trnNumber123,${trnNumber})};`

**Submit documents Thread Group**

- JSR223 PreProcessor : `${__property(trnNumber123,TransactionNo,${TransactionNoInUDV})}`; 
  //If Create Transaction is disabled then TransactionNoInUDV value considered.
- HTTP Header Manager
      Authorization
- HTTP Request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save and load properties per thread you can use suffix of _ using [__threadNum](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function:

Set property per thread

```
${__setProperty(trnNumber123 + "_" + ${__threadNum},${trnNumber})};
```

Get Property per thread:

```
${__property(trnNumber123+ "_" + ${__threadNum},
```